# local storage based react policy alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, verification

First thing I'm new to react and I have been assigned with a task.

**My task :**

I have to create one banner for policies. this banner will have browser level scope that means it will be available always once user accesses site but if user choose to close that banner it will not appear until next session.

**What I did so far? :**

I choose to go with local storage and created new component. see below code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import cx from 'classnames';
import styles from './policyAlert.scss';

class Alert extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            isActive: true
        };

        if (localStorage.getItem('policyState') === 'shown') {
            this.state = {
                isActive: false
            };
        }
    }

    hideAlert() {
        this.setState({
            isActive: false
        });
        localStorage.setItem('policyState', 'shown');
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state && this.state.isActive) {
            return (
                <div className={cx(styles.alertBottom)}>
                    <div className="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible myAlert-bottom" role="alert" style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>
                        <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" onClick={() => this.hideAlert()}>
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                       Cookie related text...
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (null);
    }
}
export default Alert;
```

Now, this code works fine for me and completing all the necessary requirements but **I'm not sure this is the best practice to achieve this kind of functionality.**

Can someone please look into it and verify? Thanks!

Comment: This is probably better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ than SO

Answer (score 1):

I don't think return `null` would be a good idea, but instead but a loading or something in there.

My suggestion would be using `componentDidMount()` for getting data out from your localstorage instead of being in `constructor` and use `setState`.

Do take note that `localStorage` is a synchronous action, which will block the code execution.

**in constructor**

```js
this.state = {
  isActive: true
};
```

**in componentDidMount**

```js
componentDidMount() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('policyState') === 'shown') {
    this.setState({
      isActive: false
    });
  }
}
```

A good example would be: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-take-advantage-of-local-storage-in-your-react-projects-a895f2b2d3f2

Comment: This will not work in once case, when user refresh page, constructor will update flag to true and componentDidMount() will not be called, so user will get policy alert even if he/she has cleared it earlier.

Comment: @Bharat in that case I would suggest to wrap this inside of a component, and conditional render that, pass in necessary data via props